# Virtual member call in constructor, sealed, and attributes

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding, resharper, custom-attributes

I have the following structures:

```
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract string Foo {get;set;}
}

public class B : A
{ 
    public B() { Foo = "test" } //ReSharper: Virtual member call in constructor

    [Bar(1, 2)]
    public override string Foo {get;set;}
}

public class C : B
{
    [Bar(2,3)]
    public override string Foo {get;set}
}
```

As you can see, I get a warning from ReSharper about making a virtual member call in the Ctor. So I thought:

- make A.Foo virtual
- make B.Foo override sealed

but then I run into the problem with I need to decorate the property with the `Bar` attribute...

I don't need to override `Foo` in `C` other than for that fact; so is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: You could create a normal property in A with a backing field, and add an overloaded constructor which sets the value of this backing field, also in A, and then chain to that constructor from B. This way there would be no virtual call in any of the constructors and you wouldn't have to seal B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are doing in B's constructor is setting a default value for Foo, just use a property with a backing field and set the default value in the field initializer:

```
public class B : A
{
 private string foo = "test";

 [Bar(1, 2)]
 public override string Foo
 {
  get { return foo; }
  set { foo = value; }
 }
}
```